# Human height estimation using one mono calibrated camera

Tags: opencv, camera, height, perspectivecamera, 3d-reconstruction

I am working on an algorithm to estimate the height of detected people in a video, and I'm stuck.

The part that I have working is the detection of people using the HoG algorithm, so I have a bounding box for every person in the frame. And I have calibrated the camera, so I have my intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters.

The problem is that now I have a formula for the perspective projection with 2 unknowns: **height** of the object and the **distance** from the object to the camera. I am using one mono web camera to detect people so I have no information about the distance from the object to the camera. And the height is what I'm trying to estimate, so I don't have that as well.

I know this problem is solvable if I use a kinect or a stereo camera in order to get the distance, but I'm limited to only one mono web camera.

Does anyone have an idea on how to approach this problem? I have read about using reference objects but I can't figure out how to use them to help my problem.

Comment: take a look at [this thesis](http://www.nada.kth.se/utbildning/grukth/exjobb/rapportlistor/2012/rapporter12/vester_johan_12040.pdf)

Comment: If you're allowed to take a video or a set of images, you can apply 3D reconstruction. Would that be of any help to you?